# Spotify AppRemote is not reconnecting once disconnected in iOS

Tags: ios, spotify

I am using Spotify in my iOS application in order to list and play a playlists. Initially I connect `appRemote` and fetch essential playlist contents with the following scopes such as .appRemote, .playlist, . playlistReadPrivate etc.

App is working fine but if I receive a phone call, then my `appRemote` was getting disconnected with the below log:

> AppRemote: Disconnected with error: Error Domain=com.spotify.app-remote.transport Code=-2001 "End of stream." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Reconnect to the Spotify app., NSLocalizedDescription=End of stream., NSLocalizedFailureReason=One of the streams has reached the end.}

I tried disconnecting appRemote in app WillResignActive state and also reenabling(Reconnecting with appRemote.connect()) in foreground state. None of them helps. Is there any way to fix this issue or we have to reauthorize once again. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried in:

```
- (void)appRemote:(SPTAppRemote *)appRemote didFailConnectionAttemptWithError:(NSError *)error
```

to handle reconnect attempts with a counter variable and increasing delay

```
[self performSelector:@selector(connect2Spotify) withObject:self afterDelay:3.0];
```

not perfect...but works in most cases..

```
-(void)connect2Spotify
{
    if (self.appRemote!=nil)
    {
        if (!self.appRemote.connected){
            self.appRemote.connectionParameters.accessToken = self.token;
            [self.appRemote connect];
        }
    }
}
```